# Testing Gradle task that uses javaexec()

Tags: gradle, spock, gradle-plugin

Suppose I have a custom Gradle task that uses `ExecOperations.javaexec()` in its code:

```
public class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    private final ExecOperations execOps
    
    @Inject
    public MyTask(ExecOperations execOps) {
       this.execOps = execOps;
    }
    
    @TaskAction
    public void run() {
        ExecResult result = execOps.javaexec(spec -> {
            // classpath is set to some jar with a main class
            spec.classpath(...);
            spec.args(...);
        });
        // Do more stuff with result
    }
}
```

The issue I have is that I am not sure how I can create a Spock test fixture for it to validate that the jar is being run with the correct arguments without actually running the jar itself. (The jar makes remote calls, for example, which I want to avoid).

It seems like the only plausible way forward is to potentially find a way to expose the `ExecOperations` for testing and possibly replace it with a stub, along with turning the `Action<JavaExecSpec>` from a mere lambda to something more substantial. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you share your specification? Stubbing `ExecOperations` and mocking `JavaExecSpec` sounds reasonable.